# How to verify that a method gets called with any argument?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I would like to `verify()` with Mockito whether or not a method gets called. Since I do not know the argument I would like to do that in such a way that it verifies with `any()` argument. Is it possible? At the moment I am getting "error, wanted x and found y".
I do not care about the parameter passed, I would like just to know if the method gets called at all. 
Thanks in advance.

As of now I have tried:

```
when(userBean.getProfile().getLanguage().getValue()).thenReturn("fr");
verify((userBean), atLeastOnce()).getProfile().getLanguage().getValue();
```

userBean has been mocked with `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS`. Getting a null pointer exception though. May be due to the fact that userBean is an EJB?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: @Matsemann sorry, updated

Comment: Which method do you want to verify? `getProfile()`, `getLanguage()` or `getValue()`?

Comment: @DanTemple getValue, I have solved it. It was to verify(userBean.getProfile().getLanguage, atLeastOnce()).getValue(); and it works, do not know why though.

Comment: If you have solved it. Please close the questions so others don't waste their time trying to solve it for you.

Comment: No, don't listen to @JohnB and "close the question". You can post your own answer, and if you don't get any better answers you can later accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the [Mockito documentation for RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> Verification only works with the last mock in the chain. You can use verification modes.

For your example:

```
 /* BAD */ verify(userBean, atLeastOnce()).getProfile().getLanguage().getValue();
/* GOOD */ verify(userBean.getProfile().getLanguage(), atLeastOnce()).getValue();
```

(Added as a separate answer to point to the documentation link.)